# How to disable outer ScrollView if inner one is scrolling?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have `ScrollView` and inside this `ScrollView` is `ListView` with items which can be scrolled vertically too. What I want to achieve is to disable parent `ScrollView` when `ListView` is scrolling.

So I found some tutorial and I made custom parent `ScrollView` where I can disable scrolling with simple Boolean value.

And I set `onTouchListener` for my `ListView` and if I touch it, it should disable parent scroll an if I release my finger, it should enable it again. But this solution is not working. Im scrolling parent and `ListView` at the same time.

Any solutions?

Code:

Custom Parent ScrollView:

```
class LockableScrollView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): ScrollView(context, attributeSet) {

    // true if we can scroll (not locked)
    // false if we cannot scroll (locked)
    private var mScrollable = true

    fun setScrollingEnabled(isEnabled: Boolean){
        mScrollable = isEnabled
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return if(ev?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
            mScrollable && super.onTouchEvent(ev)
        }else{
            super.onTouchEvent(ev)
        }
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
        // we are not scrollable
        return mScrollable && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

ListView:

```
itemListView.adapter = itemListAdapter
itemListView.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
    parentScroll.setScrollingEnabled(motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    return@OnTouchListener false
})
```